# 500 Internal Server Error on all files when GIT added <<HEAD in all of my files

Tags: php, git, apache

When I was trying to do some GIT command(I'm still a newbie in GIT), I noticed that inside all of my files have `<<HEAD----` in it. Now, what I did to remove them, I manually go to each of all of my files to remove those `<<HEAD ----`

What happens now is that even though I removed those `<<HEAD ---`, I am now getting a 500 Internal Server Error. and when I checked on my apache error logs, it shows that I have this kind of error: `premature end of script headers:`

I was also checking my .htaccess file but it seems that there were no problems inside it because I already removed the `<<HEAD---` that was produced by GIT

I got a feeling that maybe GIT was also appending some `<<HEAD---` to the files that are very important such as CGI and others. That's just a feeling though.

I really don't have any idea what that is.

Kindly guide me on this one. Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you destroyed your codebase, probably by using GIT. I have no explanation how, but it looks like. You didn't wrote what you did (do you make a worklog?), so I suggest you restore the backup from your last working version and try again. You can easily backup your GIT repository by copying over the `.git` directory, that is normally everything needed. If you didn't do any backups in the past, you might be able to restore from history.

Comment: What do you mean by restoring from history? How would I do that one? :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one by changing all my folder's permission into `755`, I also realized that when making the index.php `777`, it makes your site have an Internal Server Error.

Gosh! FOLDER PERMISSIONS!

Comment: I don't know why but some sources(google) told me that I should changed my folder permission, then I did it, then it solved! :)

Comment: Link to these sources please. I am curious as to know how that could've done it.

Comment: THis link gave me a hint: http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=425500.0